# Join other tables to return customized result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, plsql, left-join

I have the following tables

Product table:

| id | product_type | product_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | Camera | 3222333 |
| 201 | Television | 5432322 |
| 202 | PC | 4332233 |
| 203 | Mac | 1244532 |
| 204 | Notebook | 7543223 |

product_released_country1 table:

| id | product_code | released_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3222333 | 2000 |
| 2 | 3222333 | 2001 |
| 3 | 3222333 | 2003 |
| 4 | 5432322 | 2000 |
| 5 | 5432322 | 2001 |
| 6 | 5432322 | 2010 |

product_released_country2 table:

| id | product_code | released_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4332233 | 2000 |
| 2 | 4332233 | 2001 |
| 3 | 4332233 | 2009 |
| 4 | 1244532 | 2000 |
| 5 | 1244532 | 2001 |
| 6 | 1244532 | 2010 |

The products that gets released in different countries are saved in 2 different tables. I need a query that would return all products by checking both tables to see if any of the products have been released in 2010. If the product was released in 2010, then return 'yes' for the specific product. If the product hasn't been released in 2010 or haven't been released at all in any years (eg: product_code 7543223), then the query should return a 'no' for the is_product_released_in_2010 column.

**Expected output:**

| id | product_type | product_code | is_product_released_in_2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | Camera | 3222333 | no |
| 201 | Television | 5432322 | yes |
| 202 | PC | 4332233 | no |
| 203 | Mac | 1244532 | yes |
| 204 | Notebook | 7543223 | no |

I tried joining both the tables using union all but still not getting the desired result. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` and check existence

```
SELECT p.id, p.product_type, p.product_code, CASE WHEN MAX(c1.id) IS NOT NULL OR MAX(c2.id) IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END is_product_released_in_2010
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_released_country1 c1 ON p.product_code = c1.product_code AND c1.released_year = 2010
LEFT JOIN product_released_country2 c2 ON p.product_code = c2.product_code AND c2.released_year = 2010
GROUP BY p.id, p.product_type, p.product_code
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58f3be47e6ee4047b3c6b9bea62f771d)

Comment: Thanks for the query works very well. Let's say if I want to get the latest released year instead of filtering by 2010 and yes/no, (eg: for product code 3222333 - year is 2003, for 4332233 - year is 2009 and for 1244532 - year is 2010, is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: @user3376592 remove left join condition `released_year = 2010` and  `SELECT GREATEST(MAX(c1.released_year), MAX(c2.released_year))` will give you latest year for each product.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but I am getting null values for the year: SELECT p.id, p.product_type, p.product_code, GREATEST(MAX(c1.released_year), MAX(c2.released_year))
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_released_country1 c1 ON p.product_code = c1.product_code
LEFT JOIN product_released_country2 c2 ON p.product_code = c2.product_code
GROUP BY p.id, p.product_type, p.product_code

Comment: @user3376592 check this link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f204353e4e920479fccffdd31743ecb7

Comment: Wow you are a genius. Learned a lot today and thank you very much sir for your time and help. Also, one final question. Let's assume there are also other columns such as released_month, quantities_released, released_day, etc., in product_released_country1 and product_released_country2  tables. How can we get those values based on the latest_year?

Comment: @user3376592 it will be a quite different query then. similar posts at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a count and an union all

```
select 
p.id, 
p.product_type, 
p.product_code ,
(select count(*) from
  (select product_code, released_year from product_released_country1
  union all
  select product_code, released_year from product_released_country2) as t
where t.product_code = p.product_code and t.released_year=2010)>0 as is_product_released_in_2010
from product p
```

[example here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iKZCQnzBhV9NbfCPFRfizM/0)

Comment: Thank you very useful. I will try this out and I am assuming this would be faster than doing a join? Also,  if I want to get the latest released year instead of filtering by 2010 and yes/no, (eg: for product code 3222333 - year is 2003, for 4332233 - year is 2009 and for 1244532 - year is 2010, is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: I think that left join are faster, but my query is easier to understand.

To get max year you can use the following query
`select 
 p.id, 
 p.product_type, 
    p.product_code ,
    ifnull((select max(t.released_year) from
      (select product_code, released_year from product_released_country1
      union all
      select product_code, released_year from product_released_country2) as t
 where t.product_code = p.product_code ),1970) as max_year
from product p`

I've updated the [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iKZCQnzBhV9NbfCPFRfizM/1)

Comment: Thank you very much and appreciate your time.